General security/response setting, instead of defining at each endpoint
Do you really need to define 'security' and 'response' information on all endpoints? Lets say you got 100 endpoints that all identical. Is it not possible to define these settings globally?
class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *     path="/api/test/{locale}/0",
     *     summary="Test",
     *     description="Test",
     *     tags={"Test"},
     *     operationId="Test",
     *     @OA\Parameter(
     *         name="locale",
     *         in="path",
     *         description="test",
     *         required=true,
     *     ),
     *     security={ 
     *         {"bearerAuth": {}}
     *     },
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=405,
     *         description="Invalid input"
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=500,
     *         description="Server error"
     *     ),
     * )
     */
    public function test_func($locale, $country)
    { ...


Yes, you can define security and responses globally in your OpenAPI documentation to avoid repeating them for every endpoint.

Risking to state the obvious: Which absolutely makes sense, who wants to document 500 for server error etc. on every endpoint?

500 shouldn't be a documented response in any case. You're basically stating "yes, it is completely expected that my API will have server-side errors". Documented errors should only be client-side (401, 403, 404, 422).

It might not fit your use case, but if you're more interested in having an API Documentation rather than defining an API Spec, you could look at the dedoc/scramble. It automates it for you.
